# Jenkins in infinite build loop after power outage

Tags: jenkins

I was hoping someone could provide some advice. We had an unplanned power outage (>30 minutes so UPS didn't help) in the whole building. Needless to say that out Jenkins build system did not like that one bit.

Now it is stuck in an infinite loop trying to build all workspaces. But each and everyone fails. Manually canceling the builds doesn't help - they are just rescheduled right away.

None of the workspaces list any historic times or old buildlog etc. In the past I was able to get around the issue by reloading the configuration from disk. But not this time.

Can anyone provide another way of recovering from that behavior?

What I tried so far:
- Mark all nodes as offline and reboot the individual node machines after doing so.
- Mark Jenkins master for shutdown, reboot that machine.
- As mentioned above: Reload Configuration from Disk

Thanks for any advice or hints.
-T

Update:
It looks like the power outage caused a secondary system (a NAS in that case) to fail. This affected the Jenkins build because Jenkins is configured to store log files and artifacts on a network share going to the NAS.

Not being able to find the network shares caused Jenkins to fail and go into the infinite loop.

I will mark slav's comment as answer since his suggestion, although not the reason in this case, might help resolving the issue in slightly different cases.

Comment: I think you should move this question to superuser.com or something similar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You tried restarting the whole Jenkins (i.e. master) again?

Also, in the jenkins home folder, look for "queue.xml" file. Try clearing/deleting that (but make sure you have a backup first)